# Spring MVC jsp list of objects

Tags: java, html, list, spring-mvc

I use Spring MVC 3.0 and JSP. I have an object:

```
public class ObjectWrapper {
    private List<SomeTO> someTOs;
}
```

Class `SomeTO` contains fields like `name` and `id`. How can I create a form on which an user can dynamically add to list of `SomeTO`? I googled it and found something about `spring:bind`, but it's unclear for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the form backing method, set the list to a LazyList which is part of the apache commons collection library.

```
Factory notificationFactory = new Factory() {
       public Object create() {
            SomeTO rtVl = new SomeTO();
            return rtVl;
        }
 };
myFormBacking.setSomeTOs(LazyList.decorate(myFormBacking.getSomeTOs));
```

Then on your form, when you send the data to the server you can do it like this

```
<input name="someTOs[0].name" value="" />
```

And if your using

```
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

then you can simply go.

```
<form:input path="someTOs[0].name" />
```

Before posting the data to the server, to make pruning easier, set the number of elements in the collection.  So if the user added 5 TOs, then send that length value in the form post.

ON the server now, you must prune the list before you save it. Here is the function for pruning

```
public List<SomeTOs> pruneList(List<SomeTOs> unpruned,int expectedLength){
    List<SomeTOs> rtVl = new ArrayList<SomeTOs>();
    for (int i = 0; i < unpruned.length && expectedLength; ++i){
         rtVl.add(unpruned.get(i);
    }
    return rtVl;
}
```

Here is the use of the prune function in the on submit (before save)

```
wrapper.setSomeTOs(pruneList(wrapper.getSomeTOs(),Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("expectedLength)));
```

Comment: Can you explain me, what with form code? I don't understand what with command.someTOs[0].someProperty = "YES";
Sorry for crazy questions)

Comment: Hhehe, sorry... after I posted the answer I saw the properties name and Id.  Let me fix it up for you