# Spring Web - Restful Webservice - pass/receive ArrayList as an argument/parameter in client/server side

Tags: web-services, spring, rest, arraylist, resttemplate

I have created a sample application to get full idea of Spring MVC with REST Webservice. I have created an application which host webservice and a client which calls to this webservice and fetch the relevant data. I am able to pass the arguments from client side like String, and able to receive the data as List or single object, and till here it goes smooth..

Now I want to pass the List as an argument from client side, and also want to implement on webservice side to get the List which is passed from client application. Can anyone helpout with this scenario?

Please find code snippet of my working version.

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("appContext.xml", Client.class);
RestTemplate restTemplate = applicationContext.getBean("restTemplate", RestTemplate.class);
String url;
// retrieve a list of customers
url = "http://localhost:8080/restful-ws/app/testlist.xml";

List<CustomerBean> custList = (List) restTemplate.getForObject(url, List.class);
for (CustomerBean cust : custList) {
  System.out.println(">> cust :"+ cust.toString());}
```

Web Service side implementation.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/testlist")
public ModelAndView showCustomers() {
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("customerListKey");
    List<Customer> custs = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    for (Customer customer:customers.values()) {
        custs.add(customer);
    }
    mv.addObject("allCustomers", custs);
    return mv;
}
```

also i have related files, but if will put all code snippets, it will become too much. Mainly my query is how can I pass List from client side and how can i get it from receiver/server side?, in both side i am using spring only

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

-Ronak.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC jsp list of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545405/spring-mvc-jsp-list-of-objects)

Comment: @krock, i have seen the link suggested by you, but it doesn't match with this one.

Comment: @Nilesh, here my question is, using restTemplate i am able to pass the arguments, like String/Int through URL, and on server side, I am able to get that. But how can we pass List using restTemplate and on server side how can we retrieve the same List? btw Thanks for your time and help !!

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of CustomerBean

```
CustomerBean[] custList = restTemplate.getForObject(url, CustomerBean[].class);
```

The conversion from array to list is left as an exercise for the interested reader...